# Having a problem of fetching API endpoints of flask in my React App

Tags: reactjs, nginx, flask

I'm trying to fetch the /data endpoint of Flask from my React app, but I always get ECONNREFUSED from react.

Package.js

```
...
"proxy":"http://localhost:8080",
...
```

App.js

```
// Importing modules
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    // usestate for setting a javascript
    // object for storing and using data
    const [data, setdata] = useState({
        name: "",
        age: 0,
        date: "",
        programming: "",
    });

    // Using useEffect for single rendering
    useEffect(() => {
        // Using fetch to fetch the api from
        // flask server it will be redirected to proxy
        fetch('/api/data', {method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }}
).then((res) =>
            res.json().then((data) => {
                // Setting a data from api
                setdata({
                    name: data.Name,
                    age: data.Age,
                    date: data.Date,
                    programming: data.programming,
                });
            })
        )
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <h1>React and flask</h1>
                {/* Calling a data from setdata for showing */}
                <p>{data.name}</p>
                <p>{data.age}</p>
                <p>{data.date}</p>
                <p>{data.programming}</p>

            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

server.py of flask

```
# Import flask and datetime module for showing date and time
from flask import Flask
import datetime
  
x = datetime.datetime.now()
  
# Initializing flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
  
  
# Route for seeing a data
@app.route('/data')
def get_time():
  
    # Returning an api for showing in  reactjs
    return {
        'Name':"geek", 
        "Age":"22",
        "Date":x, 
        "programming":"python"
        }
  
      
# Running app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

nginx.conf to perform reverse proxy

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {

        listen 8080;

        root /usr/local/etc/nginx/build/;

        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
        location /api {
                client_max_body_size 10m;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
}
}
```

I tried many solutions but nothing worked so far. I even tried to do reverse proxy with nginx, and when I load my react app, I see in the terminal running react:
**Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/data from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080/. (ECONNREFUSED).**
but in the terminal running flask:
**127.0.0.1 - - [05/Nov/2022 21:39:24] "OPTIONS /data HTTP/1.0" 200 -** which wasn't the case when I wasn't using nginx, but I still got the issue. and my react app doesn't show anything.
I'm fairly new to this so maybe there is an obvious fix to this that I'm oblivious to?